# jQuery parse JSON in .done() functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I know that there is a shortcut to parse JSON with jQuery such as

```
$.post('myPhpFile.php', postData, function(data){
   console.log(data.status) // "OK"
},'json');
```

But I really hate anon functions and I also really hate having to manually parse JSON each time. I was hoping I could do this (because I don't always do the same thing with the same data)

```
function getSomeData(phpFile, postData){
   return $.post(phpFile, postData);
}

getSomeData.done(function(data){
   console.log(data.status) // error, as is not JSON   
},'json');
```

But in the .done() I have to $.parseJSON(data) first, and I have lots of these small functions that juts return $.posts.

Is there any other shortcut or nice functional way to still return the deferred object of $.post and have the data already parsed in json? I thought of

```
function getSomeData(phpFile, postData){
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $.post(phpFile, postData, function(data){
      defer.resolve(data);
   },'json');
   return defer.promise(data);
}
```

But I am OCD and now i have two deferreds. Just curious if there's a better way.

Comment: yes, there's a better way.  Creating extra deferred objects is a common jQuery promise _anti-pattern_.

Comment: Note: in the 2nd snippet, `getSomeData` isn't being invoked. `.done()` would be used as a method of the function itself, rather than its return value. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the `json` dataType field, but want to use Promises instead of the anonymous callback, just pass `null` for the callback.

From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

> A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds. Required if `dataType` is provided, but can be `null` in that case

Hence all you need is:

```
function getSomeData(phpFile, postData) {
    return $.post(phpFile, postData, null, 'json');
}
```

Of course if your server is responding with the appropriate `Content-type:` field then JQuery will happily just guess at the data type anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to wrap up the parameters and return an object you can chain into, wrap up a standard ajax call

```
function post(phpFile, postData){
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: phpFile,
      data: postData,
      dataType: 'json'
    });
}

post('myPhpFile.php', postData,).done(function(function(data){
   console.log(data.status)
});
```

Comment: Duh... Getting so used to the convenience functions, forgot about the originals.

Comment: @tdoakiiii `$.post` will still do what you want perfectly happily, though.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, using a `null` callback will work. I just don't like the way it looks.

Comment: @Tyrsius well, that's just being needlessly fussy, IMHO ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak I suppose; though "making the code look nice" is half of what this site is about =)

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong, I'm very much for "nice" looking code.  But even I wouldn't object to a required `null` parameter here or there.